# AES key converting to string and byte[] C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, unicode, cryptography

I have an application that generates a AES Key (using Security.Cryptography). I take that AES Key, convert it to string and put it in a cookie like this:

```
string keyToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(CurrentKey);
HttpCookie sessionKeyCookie = new HttpCookie("SessionKey", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyToSend));
```

keyToSend looks like this: "���K��Ui ����&��Ӂ*��()".

Then, I want to take back that key and use it to decrypt something, and I do this:

```
string keyString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(context.Cookies["SessionKey"].Value);
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cevaString);
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cevaString);
byte[] utf32 = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(cevaString);
```

Also, my keyToString looks like this: "���K��Ui ����&��Ӂ*��()".

And my browser cookie looks like this: "�\u0010��K��Ui �\u0010�\u000f�\u001f\u0005�\u0012\u0018&��Ӂ*��()\u001e"

**The initial key should have 256bits**, so 32 entries in that array, but all my variables (ascii, utf8, utf32) have different lengths. **Why is that, how can I retrieve the cookie and convert it to a byte[32] array?**

Comment: What is the type of `CurrentKey`? This is most likely an encoding issue.

Comment: public static byte[] CurrentKey;
I tought so, but the uncoded strings both look the same. And I applied UTF8.GetString() to the initial key, so the UT8.GetBytes() should return the initial array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `CurrentKey` is arbitrary binary data - *not* a UTF-8 encoded string. If you've got arbitrary data which you need to encode as a string (e.g. an image, or encrypted or compressed data) you're usually best off using Base64 or hex encoding. Base64 is pretty easy:

```
string keyToSend = Convert.ToBase64String(CurrentKey);
...
byte[] recoveredKey = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString);
```